# Problema con openlayers y las propiedades de sus instancias

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers

¿Puedo crear una propiedad que se llame "name" y añadirla a la instancia que he creado de esta capa?

```
var osm = new ol.layer.Tile({
    name: "pepe",
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
 })
```

Lo que quiero hacer es diferenciar esta capa de otra mediante ese nombre. Y así hacer condiciones de búsqueda. Por ejemplo: Si se llama Pepe, quiero esta capa.

---

He encontrado algo. Utilizando console.log, la estructura de este objeto para llegar al name es asi:

```
osm.N.name
```

¿Es esta la manera?

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado. Hay que utilizar el siguiente método:

```
.get('key')
```

Aplicado a mi ejemplo sería:

```
osm.get('name');
```